# Sharp.js returns incorrect dimensions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp

Sharp.js returns incorrect dimensions (low resolution) for some images when processing multiple images simultaneously. All images are having high resolution. Here is the code. Can somebody help what am I missing?

```
    let data = await sharp(file).metadata();

    if(data && data.orientation) {
        let buffer = await sharp(file).rotate().withMetadata().toBuffer();
        fs.writeFileSync(file, buffer);
    }
```